# Javascript: If statement with boolean and string comparison giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript

In my code I have the following:

```
console.log(props.acknowledged) // false
console.log(props.type === "SOMETHING") //false
console.log(!props.acknowledged && !props.type === "SOMETHING") //false
```

How is that a !false && !false results to a false?

Comment: `console.log( !false && !false ) // true`

Comment: `!props.type === "SOMETHING"` is not the same as `!(props.type === "SOMETHING")`. Precedence of operators!

Comment: I think you mean `props.type !== "SOMETHING"`. You're negating the property.

Comment: `console.log(!"foo")` ==> means you have `false === "SOMETHING"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parantheses like this: `!(props.type === "SOMETHING")`

The priority of `!` is more than `===` operator so your code will be evaluated as below:

```
!(props.type) === "SOMETHING"
```

so if `props.type` equals say `"something else"`, it will become binary value of `false` and your whole expression is `something && false` which is `false`.

I think what you wanted to to is:

```
!(props.type === "SOMETHING")
```

or even

```
props.type !== "SOMETHING"
```

Answer (score 2):

`!props.type` is negating the string, which is coercing the string to boolean (`true` in this case) which results in `false`. You are then comparing `false` to "SOMETHING" with strict equality which will always result in false. anything `&& false` will always result in `false`

As others have stated, the solution is to move the not into the comparison:

```
props.type !== "SOMETHING"
```

Just wanted to help explain the quirks of javascript's typing

Answer (score 1):

The expression `!props.type` will convert `props.type` to boolean. If it's a string, then `!props.type` means `(props.type != "")`. The subsequent `===` comparison to the string `"SOMETHING"` will always be `false`.

To put it another way,

```
!props.type === "SOMETHING"
```

is definitely not the same as

```
props.type !== "SOMETHING"
```

Perhaps what you meant was

```
!(props.type === "SOMETHING")
```

The unary `!` operator binds more tightly than `===`.